# unfiled taxes but now turning 65

Tags: taxes, canada

My friend has not filed taxes for 8 years.  He now turns 65 and wants to apply for CPP and OAP.  He did not previously file because he made very little money as a landscaper. (plowing snow and cutting grass). Where does he start to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

He should look into the **[Voluntary Disclosures Program](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/voluntarydisclosures/)**. He will have to keep up to date with his taxes thereafter, but the outcome will likely be better than if they discover he hasn't been filing before he discloses it.